# Get the runpath of a python console-script

Tags: python, runtime, setup.py

Short of it - I need to get a console_script to return to me its current run path, so that I can override modules it is using at run time.

Here is my basic setup (summarized as best I could):

```
    package_1:
      caller_module.py

    console_script_module:
      main.py
      dir_of_modules_to_use/
        a.py
        b.py
        c.py
      setup.py

    setup.py contents:
      setup(
        entry_points = {
          'console_scripts': [
            'console-script-module = console_script_module.main:main'
           ]
         }
        )
```

Longer detail:
So **caller_module.py** calls **console-script-module** by issuing a subprocess call.  In turn the modules seen in **dir_of_modules_to_use** are run.  I would like to provide my own version of those modules by overriding them right before this happens through a separate script.  In order to do this I need to know the run path of where *console-script-module* has been installed as it is not consistent (changes in virtualenv's for example).

I tried adding this in to **main.py** and using a separate command line argument to call it:

```
    def print_absoulute_dir():    
      print os.path.abspath('dir_of_modules_to_use')
```

Unfortunately this only returns the path of wherever I make the call to the console script.

DISCLAIMER - this is hacky and awful I know, it's from code I inherited and I just need something working in the short term.  I unfortunately cannot change the code within **caller_module.py** at this time, otherwise I would just change how it is calling **console_script_module:main.py**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i really understand what you want, but  every python module has the `__file__`
attribute, which contains its location in the filesystem, 
and you can use sys.path to modify python module search path

```
import urllib
import sys

print urllib.__file__
print sys.path
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused about how setup.py console_script works / what the resulting directory structure is.  I thought setup.py install just copies files to a known location and then aliases the console script call?  So I figured it should be possible to programmatically find where it has been installed.

I tried both of what you mentioned *urllib.__file__* returned "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc" and the only reference to *sys.path* about console_script_module was its egg file.

Comment: "*Perhaps I'm confused about how setup.py console_script works*"

It seems this is very much the case :-)  From the *sys.path* call where it returns the egg file, contained in there is the directory from which my console script is running from.  It's not pretty but what I can do is call *sys.path*, search in the list returned for *console_script_module* and from there find *dir_of_modules_to_use*